# Merge two data frames but only show merged data on one record

Tags: python, pandas

I'm in the process of merging two data frames, which I can do. What I'm having trouble doing is only showing merged data on a specific record. The two data frames both have ID and date. But only one date should have responses tied to it, but I would still like to show both records. Any help you could provide would be much appreciated.

For example:

```
ID | Date    | Name | Question_1   | Response_1
12  12/4/2018 John    question text  response text
12  1/1/2019  John    question text  response text
16  2/23/2019 Carol   question text  response text
23  3/01/2019 Gary    question text  response text
```

Here is what I need:

```
ID | Date    | Name | Question_1   | Response_1
12  12/4/2018 John    question text  response text
12  1/1/2019  John    
16  2/23/2019 Carol   question text  response text
23  3/01/2019 Gary    question text  response text
```

Code:

```
def data_validate(files, study):

    df1 = pd.read_csv(files[0])
    df2 = pd.read_csv(files[1])

    df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID', how='left')

    df_merge.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)

    print(df_merge)
```

Comment: Can you include df1 and df2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st convert your date back to datetime format using `to_datetime`

```
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

---

Then we using `duplicated` to `mask`

```
s=df.ID.duplicated()

df[['Question_1','Response_1']]=df[['Question_1','Response_1']].mask(s,'')
df
Out[287]: 
   ID       Date   Name    Question_1    Response_1
0  12 2018-12-04   John  questiontext  responsetext
1  12 2019-01-01   John                            
2  16 2019-02-23  Carol  questiontext  responsetext
3  23 2019-03-01   Gary  questiontext  responsetext
```

Here I am assumed your dataframe already sorted , if not using `sort_values`

Like :

```
df=df.sort_values(['ID','Date'])
```